# Magento 2.3.X static block not save any script code while saving block

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Could anyone help me to debug the issue?

Why `Magento 2.3.X` is not saving any script code in static block?

I have put some `javascript` code in the block and press the **save button** but the code is not saved.

Is there any solution to store script code in the block?

Answer (score 1):

Try `CDATA` while adding script in `cms` page or `static block`

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function($){
        //code here
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: but it's not working i have also tried with cdata but this below code din't save   <script type="text/javascript" xml="space">// <![CDATA[
 require([
            'jquery',
            'owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min'
        ], function ($) {
            $("#banner-slider-demo-7").owlCarousel({
             
            });
        });
// ]]></script>

Comment: Strange.. I have tried the same on static block and it's working

Comment: i have magento 2.3.3 version.you may have tried in different magento version

Comment: on 2.3.4 IT NOT WORKS and i think it not works in any 2.X versions.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me in magento 2.3.5 ( javascript in pub/media directory )

```
<div data-mage-init="{&quot;/media/yourjavascript.js&quot;: {}}"> </div>
```